# How to target elements inside table with css class?

Tags: html, css

what I'm currently trying to do is to have borders around and inside my table, so that all the elements are seperated. For that purpose the code works but my problem here is that if I have to use the table,tr and th elements in another instance they'll have the same attributes as the first ones. Even if I don't want them to have borders. I tried convertig the style elements into a class but if I do it that way I'll have to initialize the class in every all of the th, tr and table elements I currently have. Does anyone know a way how I could define a class that does fullfill needed function with it only be initialized inside the table tag? A class that affects all the elements inside the table in the same way the style elements do now?

```
<html>
<style>
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    tr, th, td{border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 4px;
    }
</style>

<h1> Zutrittsversuche </h1>

<table>
    <tr style="background:rgb(179, 174, 174);">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Uhrzeit</th>
        <th>Chip</th>
        <th>Chip Besitzer</th>
        <th>Tür</th>
        <th>Ergebnis</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>202x-02 17:52:12</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Schmidt</td>
        <td>Eingang Lager</td>
        <td style="color:red">Zutritt abgelehnt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>202x-02 17:52:25</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Schmidt</td>
        <td>Eingang Lager</td>
        <td style="color:red">Zutritt abgelehnt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>101</td>
        <td>202x-02-14 01:11:20</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Nettmann</td>
        <td>Eingang Büro</td>
        <td style="color:green">Zutritt gestattet</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a class to the `table` as well eg. `.table-class1`, then use nested selectors `.table-class1 .row-class1 { ... }`, `.table-class2 .row-class1 { ... }`

Comment: you can use nested selectors and `nth-child()`

Comment: why don't you migrate your code to bootstrap ? you'll have much more control over your elements there

Comment: It's an assignment and I am only allowed to use html and css sadly.